# Google Apps' Google script is duplicating in all my google docs accounts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I have a Google Spreadsheet. I have created a Script to send email alert. But the script automatically duplicates in all my Google spreadsheet / docs accounts and from each account an email is sent. How to limit this duplication of script and email sending duplication.

Comment: Are you sharing a spreadsheet across multiple accounts?  Are you copying the spreadsheet and running it in different accounts?

Comment: I am not copying spreadsheet or script. It is automatically copying script with spreadsheets. Sharing may be there but I need sharing of sheets but script for only one of the sheets.

Comment: Unless you found a bug this never happens. Show proof please.

Comment: When I add script to say myself@abc.com google apps for business accounts, the script gets copies automatically on info@abc.com. I want to avoid this copy to info@abc.com google docs account.

Comment: Either the script is badly written, or instead of writing a script, you've installed an Add-on to multiple sheets/drive. Either: 1) Post the code of your script or 2) Post a more detailed description of the 'buggy' behavior with screenshots, otherwise SO won't be able to assist.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm clear, your script is hosted in a Spreadsheet and you want to share the Sheet but not the script?

If the data is all you want to share and not edit ability, you can share a new sheet that shows the info from the original using `=IMPORTRANGE()` and just copy the formatting.

Anything else and you are describing expected behaviour.